# Communication Theory - Determine efficiency of this protocol

Tags: communication

[image]

My solution:
[image]

I have no idea if what I did is correct. I'm getting a bit confused differentiating between 500 frames/minute and the 4.8Gb/s, they both seem like transmission rates to me. 
I'm assuming 4.8Gb/s is what the channel is capable of and 500 frames/minute is what the nodes can push out.

I should add that in my lecture notes, we have that "Efficiency = Throughput(in packets/sec)*Packet Transmission Time"

Anyways, **does my answer seem correct?**

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. In my mind, *protocol efficiency* is (simplistically) determined in your case by frame payload (data) vs overhead (header), and has little or nothing to do with the channel bit rate or node frame rate. Those extra pieces of info indicate to me that your channel could handle a lot more than 2515 nodes, and with this info you've worked out *channel utilization*, not efficiency.

Comment: I should add that in my lecture notes, we have that "Efficiency = Throughput(in packets/sec)*Packet Transmission Time"

Comment: My interpretation would be more like number of bits in payload / (number of bits in playload plus header) plus any required inter frame gap or such that might be hidden the distance and speed requirement. 250m @ 4.8Gb/s for example clearly implies that many bits will be on the wire at the same time.  2500 odd nodes at that data rate is also an ouch in terms of signal integrity so there might be some overhead hidden there.